# CSS "child" selector behaves like a "descendant" selector

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply some CSS styles on a very basic html demo in order to get this result. (Only `Item 1.1` and `Item 1.2` as lowercase letter)

- ITEM 1

  - Item 1.1
  - Item 1.2
- ITEM 2
- ITEM 3

These are the html and css code snippets.

**index.html**

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Item 1
          <ul>
            <li>Item 1.1</li>
            <li>Item 1.2</li>
          </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**styles.css**

```
ul#list > li{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Which gives me the following result.

- ITEM 1

  - ITEM 1.1
  - ITEM 1.2
- ITEM 2
- ITEM 3

So as you can see the `text-transform` property is been applied on every `li` element even though `ITEM 1.1` and `ITEM 1.2` are not direct children of `ul#list`

This seems to be like the behavior of a descendant selector:

```
ul#list  li{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

text-transform is an inherited property. Specifying it on a parent also copies it down to children. Obvious, Just because you didn't set any primary property for child elements. So by default its taking that property as primary ,

`ul#list > li{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}`

```css
ul#list li {
  text-transform: none;
}

ul#list>li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>Item 1
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1.1</li>
      <li>Item 1.2
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1.1.1</li>
          <li>Item 1.2.1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you did not specify any NORMAL CSS for `<li>`

You can simply achieve this by above **`ul#list > li`**

`li
{
  text-transform: none;
}`

Please refer to this for details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors